# Создание сайта на node.js, и его загрузка на обычный сервер

Tags: node.js, сервер, хостинг

Добрый вечер!

---

Возник вопрос, по поводу загрузки Node.js на сервер.
Ранее раздобыл доступ к серверу для публикации своих работ в интернете (не такие гиганты типа Hostinger). Сервер бесплатный и на неопределённый срок (к примеру до закрытия проекта). Сама проблема состоит в том, что Создать локальный сервер с помощью Node.js я могу, а загрузить его на сервер нет.

---

К примеру есть такой [сайт](https://c9.io/) предоставляющий сервера на котором уже загружен Node.js. Заплатив небольшую цену ($5), можно спокойно работать с ним.

---

А у меня обычный сервер, где отсутствует встроенный Node, **как его туда залить, дабы не платить за лишний виртуальный хостинг, так как имеется бесплатный?!**

**P.S:** *Идёт речь о не VPS, а об обычном виртуальном хостинге(сервере).*

**P.S.S:** Корневая папка сайта на сервере ***public_html***.

Буду очень благодарен, если найдутся люди с полезной информацией для меня, или объяснением, почему нельзя (в моём случае) залить Node на мой сервер!!!

Comment: Его никак нельзя "залить", он должен исполняться как обычный системный процесс. У вас просто нет к этому доступа, поэтому это невозможно.

Comment: Виртуальный хостинг типа LAMP+cPanel не подходит, именно VPS и нужен. Раньше был неплохой вариант https://openshift.com/, но не знаю, будет ли там теперь что-то бесплатное. Они как раз 30-го удаляют все старые приложения v2, а что там на v3...